# Why do I get the error "expected type argument" when I annotate a type in a Rust function?

Tags: types, rust, capnproto

I am playing around with Rust's [capnproto library](https://github.com/dwrensha/capnproto-rust). Because Rust can infer types in some situations, I can do things like this:

```
let mut message = ::capnp::message::Builder::new_default();
```

Without having to know the type of message. If I want to pass a reference to `message` into a function, I now need to know what message is to let the function know what to expect.

Is there a convenient way to do this in general?

So far I have done the following:

```
let testing: () = message;
```

which fails with the compiler error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:197:18
    |
197 |                 let temp: () = message;
    |                           ^^^^^^^ expected (), found struct `capnp::message::Builder`
```

But when I type annotate my function as follows:

```
fn example_fn(message: capnp::message::Builder) {...}
```

I get an error like:

```
error[E0243]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0
  --> src/main.rs:72:32
   |
72 | fn dump_capnp_to_file(message: capnp::message::Builder, filename: &str) {
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected 1 type argument
```

error: aborting due to previous error

I'm very new to Rust coming from a C++ background; sorry if this a rookie question!

Comment: Do you care what the type argument is? https://docs.capnproto-rust.org/capnp/message/struct.Builder.html#method.new_default

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE]. Also include the *complete* error message. For example, those `^^^` *point at something important* but we can't tell what.

Comment: *coming from a C++ background* — you're trying to pass a `vector` instead of a `vector<int>` — does that help?

Comment: @Shepmaster the ^^^s point at capnp::message::Builder.  Should I assume that by `vector` you mean that 'Builder' is a template and needs further typing information?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to have the *complete error message*; comments are not for additional information.

Comment: See updated question

Comment: I think I figured out your problem (see my answer), but I also think you replaced the wrong error with your edit. Please reread it and make sure you're posting both error messages in their entirety

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rust *will not* infer types in function parameter position. This is by design, as the [Rust language FAQ](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/faq.html#why-arent-function-signatures-inferred) states:

> ### Why aren't function signatures inferred?
>
> In Rust, declarations tend to come with explicit types, while actual code has its types inferred. There are several reasons for this design:
>
> - Mandatory declaration signatures help enforce interface stability at both the module and crate level.
> - Signatures improve code comprehension for the programmer, eliminating the need for an IDE running an inference algorithm across an entire crate to be able to guess at a function’s argument types; it’s always explicit and nearby.
> - Mechanically, it simplifies the inference algorithm, as inference only requires looking at one function at a time.

Since `capnp::message::Builder<A>` takes a type parameter `A`, you need to qualify the type of the parameter by giving `A` a value:

```
fn dump_capnp_to_file(message: capnp::message::Builder<SomeType>, filename: String) {
//                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^
```

or else make your function also generic so it can accept any type `A`:

```
fn dump_capnp_to_file<A>(message: capnp::message::Builder<A>, filename: String) {
//                   ^^^                                 ^^^
```

#### Putting bounds on `A`

If you take the last option, you might want additional [trait bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/traits.html#trait-bounds-on-generic-functions) to allow you to do different things with `message` inside the function. For example, you might want to send `message` to another thread, which requires that `Builder<A>` implement `Send`. `Builder` has the following impl ([reference](https://docs.capnproto-rust.org/capnp/message/struct.Builder.html)):

```
impl <A> Send for Builder<A> where A: Send + Allocator
```

which means that `Builder<A>` can implement `Send`, but only when `A` implements `Send` and `Allocator`. You can make that your own bound (requirement) on `A`:

```
fn dump_capnp_to_file<A>(message: capnp::message::Builder<A>, filename: String)
    where A: Send + Allocator
{
    // multi-threaded code...
}
```

Alternatively (and maybe slightly better), bound `Builder<A>` with `Send` directly:

```
fn dump_capnp_to_file<A>(message: capnp::message::Builder<A>, filename: String)
    where capnp::message::Builder<A>: Send
```

Then you will only be able to call `dump_capnp_to_file` on a `Builder` that implements `Send`.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by bounds on A please?

Comment: @JMzance I'll do that if you fix the error messages in your question. Deal? ;-)

Comment: @JMzance Done. This actually isn't a great example of when to use trait bounds, but when I originally answered I couldn't access the capnproto documentation to know that so I guessed it might be desirable